# How can I programmatically draw a nonlinear writing system with automatic graph relaxation?

Tags: graphics, languages, programming, graphs

Alex Fink & I have a non-linear written language, [UNLWS](http://s.ai/nlws). Maintaining its grammar document in Google Docs is growing excessively cumbersome, however, because of how much time it takes to load each image — and the images created for embedding in gdocs are not really combinable and exportable in a good way.

UNLWS is primarily composed of a variety of [glyphs](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1y15nvR28xPxZMF-pFypB4zaxUAzblj3cG2SjvnGIO44#h.1hjx9gpo5w8q) — which are basically small pieces of vector art with specified binding points (the little blue circles in the glossary) — and which all interconnect with each other at those binding points like a graph (as in trees, not bars) using a variety of methods (mainly simple lines).

Some glyphs have internal structure as well, e.g. variable line or arc length, spline curvature, distance of segments, etc., and some have bindings that aren't drawn with lines (e.g. [articles](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1y15nvR28xPxZMF-pFypB4zaxUAzblj3cG2SjvnGIO44#h.dsjl18nb1v8b)).

In general, so long as the glyphs are connected properly and follow some rules about how to connect (e.g. avoid crossings, make smooth or straight lines where possible, relax the graph), the result will be licit.

However, there are also non-graph components, such as cartouches that surround or divide portions of the text, and some cases where certain glyphs must be near each other and placed with specific orientation or distance with respect to each other.

In some cases, we'd also want to hint the graphics package about how to do the layout more aesthetically, e.g. for [poetry](http://s.ai/poetry/st_francis) (note the cartouches in the center and sides) or [stories](http://eaworld.conlang.org/relays/relay19/relay19.php?ring=3&torch=04&ringlish=N&tlit=n&torchlish=y&reverse=n) (note the black-dashed dividing lines of three varieties). For some simpler examples, see our [scratchpad](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1k1qaEHNRSGNsH0pJvvGtPe6ZSHFUmlpnwyZbcjIK7uQ/edit?pli=1).

Ideally, we would like to be able to compose this in *TeX using a reasonable graphics library that would support this, e.g. being able to:

- define reusable glyphs (with variables)
- tell the package what glyphs to connect at what binding points, and have it figure out how to do the necessary graph relaxation etc, with at least a reasonable-looking result
- optionally hint the package on how to do the layout
- add English text in various places with alignment / snapping (there is none in UNLWS itself, but it's useful for documentation)
- export to a standard vector format, eg for printing posters or shirts

What would be a good way to do this?

I've deliberately phrased this in an open-ended way, as I don't know what an appropriate approach or package set would be (or if LaTeX is even appropriate in the first place). I would imagine that parts of the problem (e.g. graph relaxation) have been addressed by packages like TikZ (which was [going to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17977) add GraphViz neato-like support in 2011? ), but I'm not at all familiar with them.

(FWIW: Both of us are coders. I have hardly ever used *TeX before; Alex is a mathematician, and therefore does so a lot, and has used Asymptote before for other things.)

Comment: The [`pythontex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex) package "allows you to enter Python code within a LaTeX 
document, execute the code, and access its output in the original document.
It also supports the Ruby, Julia, and Octave languages."