# How to automatically draw a graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, miktex, graphs

Is there a simple package for which I can input an abstract graph and it returns a drawing?

A [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/how-to-automatically-draw-a-graph-in-latex) was asked in 2010, it did not receive any answers relevant to my question.
I want no complicated code, just give the edge-list of the graph and get any drawing.
(Of course a few optional parameters are welcome.)
This is already implemented in many programming languages, so I suppose it should also be available in LaTeX.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically draw a graph in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/how-to-automatically-draw-a-graph-in-latex)

Comment: @Andrestand That's a pretty old reference. TikZ now has a fullblown graphdrawing library.

Comment: @percusse I don't know very well the SE rules, but wouldn't it be more appropriate then to *reactivate* the original question?

Comment: @Andrestand If you feel like it yes please do. But it's not strictly required in this case. We rather work on guidance/community agreement bases. **Reviewers** Don't you read any meta questions?

Comment: @percusse I don't understand what you mean. Wouldn't be more efficient (in order to make easily-accessible answers to common questions, etc) to merge the modern answer to the current post into the duplicate? What meta question do you have in mind?

Comment: @Andrestand I don't mind merging my question with the old one, please do so, if you find it best, I don't know the policy. (I am not sure why you had to announce possible duplicate when I've stated so in my original question.)

Comment: @domotorp The comment is added automatically by the system when the duplicate vote is registered.

Comment: @tohecz That makes it even more mysterious why Andrestand also added his comment.

Comment: @domotorp You mean because he has not enough reputation? Probably a flag vote was used.

Comment: @T.Verron If updated yes, otherwise there is no point merging with an old question. So it's not fair to close a question as a duplicate **before** the general one is updated. Especially when a question mentions an old answer.

Comment: @percusse Ah, indeed. I spent too much time reading the comments and skipped that link in the question, my bad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are at least two ways:

1. the most flexible (and the one I recommend) is using [PGF3/TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/)'s automatic layout facilities available if you have a recent version of the package (version 3.0.0 and above) and if you use `luatex`/`lualatex` to compile. See the PGF manual, there's a chapter dedicated to this.
   The advantage is that you can use the full power of TikZ to style your nodes/edges and it would blend seamlessly with the rest of the document.
   You can use (almost) arbitrary TeX code for labels/node contents and TikZ styles.
   The disadvantage could be performance, but you could alleviate this by using the `external` library (see the manual).

   An example from the manual:

   ```
   \tikz [>=spaced stealth’]
   \graph [layered layout, components go right top aligned, nodes=draw, edges=rounded corners]
   {
       first root -> {1 -> {2, 3, 7} -> {4, 5}, 6 }, 4 -- 5;
       second root -> x -> {a -> {u,v}, b, c -> d -> {w,z} };
       third root -> child -> grandchild -> youngster -> third root;
   };
   ```

   [image: example]
2. use graphviz to generate the layout and then use [`dot2tex`](http://dot2tex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The advantage is that you still get the same fonts as your main document, you can use math and you can compile the graph once and avoid doing the layout at every compilation of the document.

   There are ways to automate the latter using the LaTeX package `dot2texi`. 
   Remember to run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option to make this work: `dot2texi` will need to invoke the external `dot2tex` tool which needs to be installed (depends on python) along with `graphviz`.
   With recent versions you have the option to generate TikZ code and specify custom TikZ styles for nodes/edges.
   A quote from the docs:

   > The output from Graphviz and dot2tex is not perfect. Manual adjustments are sometimes necessary to get the right results for use in a publication. For final and cosmetic adjustments, it is often easier to edit the generated code than to hack the dot source. This is especially true when using the tikz output format.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced by the last sentence. If you're using TikZ, you have plenty of possibilities to customize graphviz nodes. See [Drawing relationships between elements of a database](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78357/13304).

Comment: Ah, actually that is based on experiments done a long time ago, I see now that `dot2tex` evolved considerably...I might add that to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Could I also ask you to tell me what packages to load? I've tried for an hour, have been reading the manual, but I cannot make your example translate. Can the problem be that I use MiKTeX? If so, are there any solutions that work with MiKTeX?

Comment: which option are you using? with 1 you will need `tikz`, `\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}` and `\usegdlibrary{layered}` + compiling using `lualatex`. See chapter IV of manual...

Comment: @domotorp Specifically you need TikZ/PGF v3.00. Probably you need to update your distribution too.

Comment: Well, actually I wanted a simpler solution than installing a new compiler... Please let me know if you have a solution that works with MiKTeX.

Comment: @domotorp Lua(La)TeX is part of MikTeX too, there's nothing stopping you from using it there.

Comment: @Paul Oh, cool, then I suppose I only have to figure out how to install the missing library...

Comment: @domotorp just use the MikTeX Package Manager to update the `pgf` package to the current version.

Comment: Where does this example go? Inside \beging{tikzpicture}?

Comment: @mathtick the example is taken from https://tikz.dev/gd-overview#sec-27.2 there's a whole section dedicated just to graph drawing