# Automatical graph layout with high number of connections using TikZ package

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, graphs

While learning to work with LaTeX, I have found out (also in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203692/how-to-automatically-draw-a-graph)) that TikZ is able to create very good automatic graph layouts. In my work, I had assignment to create pretty large interconnected graph (about 100 nodes, hundreds of connections), which I sadly had to do manually (in Word, nasty business). And here I go to se that it can be done with TikZ, but you have to compile the .tex with LuaLaTeX.

1. Does anybody have experience with this? Are thre any limitations?
2. More specifically, ideally I would like to create graph, that would span more than 1 page, and one that would have no or very little amount of crossings of node connections. Did anybody tried that, or is any expert willing to elaborate?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I am afraid that this is not an answerable question as long as you do not make it more concrete. For instance, the second graph in the post you link to is a tree, and yes, it is possible to [run a tree over several pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356922/121799). Generally, however, it is hard to run a tikzpicture over more than one page.

Comment: @marmot Thank you for your reply.
Would help then if I provide at least picture of graph mentioned in the question above? Its not exactly what I want to do, but it could make my question specific enough and the answers could be aplicable, or could help me create more specific (another) question.

Thing is, it will take me some time, I have to hide confidential info (delete all text inside nodes). No problem for me, if it will be of any value for you.

Comment: It might help but even then this will not necessarily be considered an answerable question by many users here. Typical questions are something like "I tried this but got stuck here...".

Comment: [`sa-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sa-tikz) does something on this line (totally automated and can span thousands of nodes). This project is however very specific, and might lead you totally out of route... it depends on which is your ultimate goal.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, look into it shortly and it seems usable for me to some extent, eventhough I go more @marmot way, to try to replicate my old graph and post as much specific issues as I can as I go :D
As long as were talking here, I would like to finish with last subquestion.

While reading pgf manual, am I on the right place while starting reading ch. 31 (Graph drawing algorithm); given I read through the basics in the beginning?
A direction where to go would be great for me, since I cant read through the whole thing.. :D